# What does 'yep clock' mean?

Tags: idioms, terminology, slang

Been seeing this term on twitch lately.
For example, it is referred to starting at
19 min 00 secs of this video https://www.twitch.tv/videos/821017035
Is it some meme or slang term?

Comment: It's a clock that idiot puppets say "Yep" around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Yep" is an emote of Pepe on Twitch.
"Yep clock" is a graphic of this emote and a clock.

Comment: Yep, if you Google it you get videos of the puppets saying "Yep".

Comment: @grouchdoug lmao reread what you said

Comment: So if it is a reference to the image of Pepe with/on a clock, what does it then convey when you SAY "Yep clock"? A sarcastic yes?